# Showing the big Oh bound for the logarithmic integral $\operatorname{Li}(x)=x/\log x + x/\log^2 (x)+O(x/\log^3 (x))$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, estimation

Consider the logarithmic integral $\operatorname{Li}(x):=\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}.$

Then I found a result stating that we have $\operatorname{Li}(x)=x/\log x+O(x/\log^2(x))$ and another integration by parts gives $\operatorname{Li}(x)=x/\log x + x/\log^2 (x)+O(x/\log^3 (x))$.

I can see that integration by parts gives $\int_2^x dt/ \log t=x / \log x - 2/ \log x +\int_2^x dt/ log^2(t)$.

And integrating by parts again gives $\int_2^x dt/ \log t=x / \log x - 2/ \log x +x/\log^2 x-2/\log^2 2 + 2\int_2^x dt/\log^3t.$

So it seems like we should have $\int_2^x dt/\log^3 t = O(x/\log^3 x)$ but I don't know how to prove this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this right?  I think the term $+ x/\log^2 (x)$ is redundant together with $+O(x/\log^2 (x))$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for pointing it out it's 3 inside the big Oh not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Split the interval of integration in $[2,\sqrt x]$ and $[\sqrt x, x]$. Use a trivial bound on each interval (the function is decreasing). Try that. If you have trouble I could give you more details.

Comment: Could you give me more details. With this splitting I get the simple bound $\frac{\sqrt x}{\log^3 2} + \frac{x}{\log^3 (\sqrt x)}$.

Comment: I guess we can then use the fact that $\log^2(\sqrt(x))=1/8 \log(x)$. And since $\sqrt(x)\ge \log^3 x $ for large $x$ we have $\sqrt(x) \le \frac{x}{\log^3 x}$ and so the first term must be $O(\frac{x}{\log^3 x})$ as well. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's (almost) correct, just check the exponents

Comment: When typing square roots use `\sqrt{x}` instead of `\sqrt(x)`

Answer (score 2):

By L'Hôpital's rule,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{\displaystyle\int_2^x {\frac{{\mathrm{d}t}}{{\log ^3 t}}} }}{{\displaystyle\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{\displaystyle\frac{1}{{\log ^3 x}}}}{{\displaystyle\frac{1}{{\log ^3 x}} - \frac{3}{{\log ^4 x}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{\displaystyle1 - \frac{3}{{\log x}}}} = 1.
$$